# Managing a Yii app with Git

Tags: git, github, yii

If I have a public Git repository for my Yii app. I'm wondering how I would keep DB config settings private? I can't ignore the whole file.

Comment: You can decompose your config to smaller files. Extract DB config to a separate file and ignore *that*.

Comment: If you don't need a public git repo, you could always just make a private one on bitbucket (instead of github), because you can have unlimited private repos on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

Answer (score 7):

Create second ignored config and merge results:

```
$config=require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php');

$configIgnored=require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/ignored.php');

require_once($yii);

$config = CMap::mergeArray($config, $configIgnored);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Answer (score 2):

**First ...**
Keep in your repository a protected/config/main.php.dist file. 'dist' stands for 'distribution'. This file is a normal config file but without sensible data. For example you can have:

```
...
'db' => array(
  'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=[[hostname]];dbname=[[database]]',
  'emulatePrepare' => true,
  'username' => '[[username]]',
  'password' => '[[password]]',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
),
...
```

Keep in mind that your username, password, ... are not project stuff. This informations regard only you and not your application.

**Second...**
Prepare your application for deploy. For example I use phing in this way:

```
<project name="yourProject" default="install">
    <target name="install" description="Prepare application for deploy">
        <input propertyname="hostname"
               defaultValue="localhost" promptChar="?">hostname</input>
        <input propertyname="database"
               defaultValue="database" promptChar="?">database</input>
        <input propertyname="username" defaultValue="root" promptChar="?">username</input>
        <input propertyname="password" defaultValue="root" promptChar="?">password</input>
        <copy file="protected/config/main.php.dist"
              tofile="protected/config/main.php"
              overwrite="false">
            <filterchain>
                <replacetokens begintoken="[[" endtoken="]]">
                    <token key="username" value="${username}" />
                    <token key="password" value="${password}" />
                    <token key="hostname" value="${hostname}" />
                    <token key="database" value="${database}" />
                </replacetokens>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

By this way, you'll never store config settings in your repository and just need to run

```
$ phing install
```

to config application in your machine. Obviously you need to have phing installed.

Answer (score 1):

Found this, which works perfectly: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/33395-best-practices-to-separate-db-connection-credentials-from-mainphp-and-git-repository/

Answer (score 0):

i don't use Yii so i don't know its structure but one thing i know is, you can't ignore line(s) of a file with git. So i prefer you to gitignore your real configuration file and instead of the real file, also create a config_sample file to publish and write down the instructions to get it work into README.md